# How can I be sure the CPU is the failing component when all attempts at OS boot fail

Tags: cpu, bsod, components

Basically i have tried a wide range of ways to identify exactly which component has failed, but seem to have eliminated all components but the CPU, from here I am unsure how to verify this is the problematic component, and want to confirm this before I try send it back to Intel.

Problem description:

This all started while I was running a game (Age of Empires 3), I built the system around half a year prior and it had been working well for the previous half year. All of a sudden I got a windows blue screen of death (BSOD). When attempting to start the computer from this point forward, it would get in a BSOD loop, with windows attempting to repair itself but then BSODing and restarting. I noted down the error codes, which seemed almost random and probably not relevant, the codes included:

- Page fault in nonpaged area
- IRQL Not Less or Equal
- System Thread exception not handled
- Kmode Exception not handled
- Critical process died
- Unexpected kernel mode trap

From this point onward when booting from any of the following sources, the system will freeze with a BSOD for windows, or just simply freeze the boot screen when running live linux. Sources tried:

1. SSD HDD (Windows 10 Installed previously)
2. USB (Mounted Widnows 10 Install)
3. DVD (Windows 10 Install Disk)
4. DVD (Live Linux GNU / KNOPPIX)

My system specs are:

- **MSI Z170A Gaming M5 Motherboard**
- **Intel Core i7-6700K 4GHz 2978874**
- Cryorig H7 CPU Cooler
- **Corsair 16GB (2x8G)** CMK16GX4M2B3000C15B DDR4 3000MHz Vengeance LPX
  Blue Memory
- Asus GTX 660 Ti DirectCU II 2gb GDDR5 PCIE3.0
- Samsung 120gb SSD, Samsung 1tb sata, Western Digital 2tb sata
- LG GH-22LS50 22X LightScribe Black SATA DVD Writer
- Silverstone 500W SST-ST50F-230

I have tried the following configurations, with all producing the same OS freeze, after running for a second:

1. Removing all hdd's and only booting from DVDRom
2. Removing one (and the other of 2) memory sticks, and using different
   memory slots on MB.
3. Removing the graphics card, and using the on-board hdmi port.
4. Changing the Rom Drive to another DVD drive.
5. Changing the motherboard to a very similar but new Mobo I purchased
   (MSI Z270 GAMING M5, with new/re-applied thermal paste).
6. Running the above in the minimalists configuration possible, eg
   Mobo+single ram stick+usb boot.

I have also run various memory and CPU diagnostics I could find, with nothing turning up anything interesting.

I am really looking for:

- Confirmation that I have done all I can, and can feel confident the problem lies in the CPU.
- Possibly any additional hardware changes or software I can run to try
  diagnose the problem.

Comment: Have you been able to monitor CPU temperature?

Comment: Checked temperatures, all is well within normal (also checked voltages across components, all normal Also)

Comment: It is a tough situation. Could be your MB as well. What is puzzling you can run some tests on it so something is working. Have you tried boot Linux on safe mode, or boot Windows setup?

Comment: Yeah tried replacing mobo, and have tried windows boot from both disk and usb; but no luck :( is it likely or possible both memory sticks failed at the same time?

Comment: Well i am thinking to boot from installation disk. Suppose there is problem with your windows installation. Boot from Windows install DVD should be different then. With Linux not sure how much experience you have but there are ways of loading something simple and then running tests on hw. First and foremost memtest and there are others.

Comment: @r0berts maybe i was not clear. I have tried Booting from all the list of options in the original post (win10 install disk is one of them)

Comment: Sure, but you say you've run some tests various memory and CPU diagnostics, so you boot into something. Or is it from bios? What tests?

Comment: Ahh right, sorry, i tried: hirens bootcd for memory and an intel test for the cpu (http://www.tcsscreening.com/files/users/IPDT_LiveUSB/index.html).

Comment: share the dmp files from c:\windows\minidump

Comment: The way to be sure it is not your operating system disk that is making the trouble would be to _disconnect_ the HDD, put in new or any formatted HDD and try install any system on that. I am saying this because you can boot hiren and this suggests hardware is fine. If you are successful, then think of a way to safely get data off your original HDD.

Comment: I had eliminated the OS Disk, by running it in the minimalist config (mobo+cpu+ram+usb boot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further discussion with others (it sounds like the above covered my cases pretty well). I was satisfied that there was a high chance it was a CPU issue. I purchased a new 7700k, and suddenly everything started working again. Will be sending old cpu back to intel soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is already an accepted answer, but for the benefit of others:

The next step in the investigative process would be to take the OS out of the equation.  In other words, boot to another OS, such as a live Linux CD, or just poke around in the BIOS settings for a few minutes.  If the problem is indeed hardware related, you're likely to see flakey behavior there as well.